# Passing value from callback in component to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, callback

I am using giphy-api module from nodejs and I want to pass this data to react.

I have two components:

Api.js is the one that successfully connects with node.js and returns a callback with all the API data.
App.js is the main component. I import Api.js and when I console.log this callback message it works.
I tried props and states but because the Api.js returns a Callback I don't know how to consume it.

Api.js

```
import openSocket from "socket.io-client";
const socket = openSocket("http://localhost:5000/");

function connect(cb) {
  // listen for any messages coming through
  // of type 'chat' and then trigger the
  // callback function with said message
  socket.on("chat", message => {
    // trigger the callback passed in when
    // our App component calls connect
    cb(message);
  });
}

export { connect };
```

App.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from './api';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // call our connect function and define
    // an anonymous callback function that`
    // simply console.log's the received
    // message
    var gifs = connect(message => {
      console.log(message);
    });
    this.state = {
            books: [
                {
                    name: 'Zero to one',
                    isbn: '9780804139298',
                    author: 'Peter Thiel',
                    cover: 'https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1414347376l/18050143.jpg',
                    status: false
                }
      ],
      gipphy: gifs
        };
  }

  render () {

      return (
        <div className=".App-logo">
            <li className=".App-logo">
              <img src={ this.state.books[0].cover} alt="gipphy.com animations"/>
              <img src={ this.state.gifs[0].images.original.url} alt="gipphy.com animations"/>
            </li>
      </div>
    )
      }
}

export default App;
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'gipphy' of null

Now the console.log is undefined

Comment: Seems like the problem is with `this.state.gifs[0]`. Do you need to define gifs in state (currently it's books and giphy within state)?

Comment: What it prints `console.log(message);`?

Comment: Hi staminna, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Comment: this is my first real react app, and I still don't understand much about states. I am not sure if I actually need it, but I think the problem is with the way that Api.js handles the callback and doesn't use return. ps: I tried to make it return but didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is because, you have stored `gifs` value in `gipphy` state variable. So instead of `this.state.gifs` you should use `this.state.gipphy`,

```
<img src={ this.state.gipphy[0].images.original.url} alt="gipphy.com animations"/>
```

Also make sure `gifs` contains correct value. Simply make a `console.log(gifs)` in a constructor. If you don't get `gifs` value, then I think you need to return it from callback,

```
var gifs = connect(message => {
   console.log(message);
   return message;   //return the message here
});
```

---

**Update**

I think your API is taking time to return data. You can make use of `componentDidMount` method,

```
componentDidMount(){
   connect(message => {
      this.setState({
          gipphy: message
      })
   });
}
```

You need to conditionally render your `img`,

```
{this.state.giphy && this.state.giphy.length > 0 && <img src={ this.state.giphy[0].images.original.url} alt="giphy.com animations"/>}
```

Comment: After returning the message, the gifs variable is undefined.

Comment: I think that is because of the was that Api.js is designed to return the callback. Can you help?

Comment: When you print message using `console.log(message)`, what you get?

Comment: The Array I'm looking after, but printing gif returns undefined.

Comment: yu need to initialize the state `gipphy` using empty array like `gipphy: []`

Comment: The gipphy variable is now undefined because I think the state is now [ ]. The error is now TypeError: Cannot read property 'images' of undefined
:(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199770/discussion-between-ravibagul91-and-staminna).